# Single-Line Contenteditable DIV that Scrolls without Scrolls

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

This CSS is applied to a contenteditable DIV (inside the BODY) in Firefox 15. I was expecting that as I type the field will get full of text and starts scrolling horizentally automatically (without showing scrolls) so that the caret and the last typed text is visible, but that is not the case with me.

Any ideas?

```
.al-field {
background-color: pink;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
width: 200px;
height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I do not want the scrolls to be visible

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox 19.

Comment: Yes it does work fine in latest FF, so is it a bug in older FF? Any work arounds?